# Collision Detection not being recognized

Tags: android, collision-detection

I am  trying to make a game and I am about to finish it.But the problem is my Collision detection is not being recognized. the score just keeps adding.
They told me to move it to LibGdx. But it would be a hassle now considering I am about to finish the game. I am just worried my app would crash if I did not use a library. Do you guys think I should move to LibGdx?

this is my code only for the collision detection part..Is there something wrong with my code?
I am really struggling with collision detection. I will appreciate any help.

```
       animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation animation) {
            if(checkRedCollision() && checkRedCollision2() && checkBlueCollision() && checkBlueCollision2()
                    && checkYellowCollision() && checkYellowCollision2() && checkGreenCollision2() && checkGreenCollision())
            {
                Score++;
            }else {
                Score--;
            }


                mhandle.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mtvscore.setText("" + Score);
                        ballcolor=random.nextInt(4);
                        ballcolor2=random.nextInt(4);
                        ballcolor3=random.nextInt(4);
                        ball1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_0 + ballcolor);
                        ball2.setImageResource(R.drawable.row2_0 + ballcolor2);
                        ball3.setImageResource(R.drawable.row3_0 + ballcolor3);

                        // now we restart the animation
                        animation.setDuration(7500);
                        ball1.startAnimation(animation);
                        ball2.startAnimation(animation);
                        ball3.startAnimation(animation);

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        animation.setDuration(6500);
        ball1.startAnimation(animation);
        ball2.startAnimation(animation);
        ball3.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    public boolean checkRedCollision() {
        return checkCollisionR(ball1, rr, rg);
    }
    public boolean checkRedCollision2() {
        return checkCollisionR2(ball1, ry, rb);
    }
    public boolean checkBlueCollision() {
        return checkCollisionB(ball3, br, bg);
    }
    public boolean checkBlueCollision2() {
        return checkCollisionB2(ball3, br, bg);
    }
    public boolean checkGreenCollision() {
        return checkCollisionG(ball4, gr, gg);
    }
    public boolean checkGreenCollision2() {
        return checkCollisionG2(ball4, gy, gb);
    }
    public boolean checkYellowCollision() {
        return checkCollisionY(ball2, yr, yg);
    }
    public boolean checkYellowCollision2() {
        return checkCollisionY2(ball2, yy, yb);
    }

    public boolean checkCollisionR(final View ball1, final View rr, final View rg) {
        Rect R1 = new Rect(ball1.getLeft(), ball1.getTop(), ball1.getRight(), ball1.getBottom()); //red
        Rect R2 = new Rect(rr.getLeft(), rr.getTop(), rr.getRight(), rr.getBottom());
        Rect R3 = new Rect(rg.getLeft(), rg.getTop(), rg.getRight(), rg.getBottom());
        return R1.setIntersect(R2, R3);
    }
    public boolean checkCollisionR2(final View ball1, final View ry, final View rb) {
        Rect R1 = new Rect(ball1.getLeft(), ball1.getTop(), ball1.getRight(), ball1.getBottom()); //red
        Rect R2 = new Rect(ry.getLeft(), ry.getTop(), ry.getRight(), ry.getBottom());
        Rect R3 = new Rect(rb.getLeft(), rb.getTop(), rb.getRight(), rb.getBottom());
        return R1.setIntersect(R2, R3);
    }
    public boolean checkCollisionY(final View ball2, final View yr, final View yg) {       //
        Rect R1 = new Rect(ball2.getLeft(), ball2.getTop(), ball2.getRight(), ball2.getBottom());
        Rect R2 = new Rect(yr.getLeft(), yr.getTop(), yr.getRight(), yr.getBottom());
        Rect R3 = new Rect(yg.getLeft(), yg.getTop(), yg.getRight(), yg.getBottom());
        return R1.setIntersect(R2, R3);
    }
    public boolean checkCollisionY2(final View ball2, final View yy, final View yb) {
        Rect R1 = new Rect(ball2.getLeft(), ball2.getTop(), ball2.getRight(), ball2.getBottom());
        Rect R2 = new Rect(yy.getLeft(), yy.getTop(), yy.getRight(), yy.getBottom());
        Rect R3 = new Rect(yb.getLeft(), yb.getTop(), yb.getRight(), yb.getBottom());
        return R1.setIntersect(R2, R3);
    }
    public boolean checkCollisionB(final View ball3, final View br, final View bg) {
        Rect R1 = new Rect(ball3.getLeft(), ball3.getTop(), ball3.getRight(), ball3.getBottom());
        Rect R2 = new Rect(br.getLeft(), br.getTop(), br.getRight(), br.getBottom());
        Rect R3 = new Rect(bg.getLeft(), bg.getTop(), bg.getRight(), bg.getBottom());
        return R1.setIntersect(R2, R3);
    }
    public boolean checkCollisionB2(final View ball3, final View yy, final View yb) {
        Rect R1 = new Rect(ball3.getLeft(), ball3.getTop(), ball3.getRight(), ball3.getBottom());
        Rect R2 = new Rect(yy.getLeft(), yy.getTop(), yy.getRight(), yy.getBottom());
        Rect R3 = new Rect(yb.getLeft(), yb.getTop(), yb.getRight(), yb.getBottom());
        return R1.setIntersect(R2, R3);
    }
    public boolean checkCollisionG(final View ball4, final View gr, final View gg) {
        Rect R1 = new Rect(ball4.getLeft(), ball4.getTop(), ball4.getRight(), ball4.getBottom());
        Rect R2 = new Rect(gr.getLeft(), gr.getTop(), gr.getRight(), gr.getBottom());
        Rect R3 = new Rect(gg.getLeft(), gg.getTop(), gg.getRight(), gg.getBottom());
        return R1.setIntersect(R2, R3);
    }
    public boolean checkCollisionG2(final View ball4, final View gy, final View gb) {
        Rect R1 = new Rect(ball4.getLeft(), ball4.getTop(), ball4.getRight(), ball4.getBottom());
        Rect R2 = new Rect(gy.getLeft(), gy.getTop(), gy.getRight(), gy.getBottom());
        Rect R3 = new Rect(gb.getLeft(), gb.getTop(), gb.getRight(), gb.getBottom());
        return R1.setIntersect(R2, R3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may give you an idea why your code collision is not working. We are trying to only have collision to be true when certain sides intersect both image views are moving one up and down and the other left and right

```
    public void onFIRE(View view){

    ZX += 100;
    ZY += 0;

    arrowLeft.setX(ZX);
    arrowLeft.setY(arrowLeft.getY()+ZY);
    hitCHECK();

}

public void hitCHECK(){

    Rect arrowLeftRect = new Rect();
    arrowLeft.getHitRect(arrowLeftRect);
    Rect arrowRightRect = new Rect();
    arrowRight.getHitRect(arrowRightRect);

    int Lbottom = arrowLeftRect.bottom;
    int Ltop = arrowLeftRect.top;
    int Lleft = arrowLeftRect.left;
    int Lright = arrowLeftRect.right;
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$ Left bottom "+Lbottom+" Top "+Ltop+" Left 
    "+Lleft+" Right "+Lright);

    int Rbottom = arrowRightRect.bottom;
    int Rtop = arrowRightRect.top;
    int Rleft = arrowRightRect.left;
    int Rright = arrowRightRect.right;
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$ Right bottom "+Rbottom+" Top "+Rtop+" Left 
    "+Rleft+" Right "+Rright);

    if(arrowLeftRect.right > arrowRightRect.right){
        arrowLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        arrowLeft.setX(-100);
        arrowLeft.setY(-100);

    }
```

Comment: this is a lot of help,but do you think I should go and move to libgdx? will the app function the same? I'm worried it will be more efficient and functional if I move to libgdx

Answer (score 0):

As for LIBgdx it looks like fun but if it can be done in Java why complicate the process. Here is some code that we used in a very rudimentary 2D game called Asteroids. The ship that fires does not fly the screen seemed too small for flying. We wrote the same game with JavaFX for desktop and used very different collision detetion. We are not pro game developers so this may seem slow to some folks. The Image View pink fires at various Image View asteroids that move around the screen. Size matters here the pink bullet is only 16 by 16 and the asteroids are all 46 by 48 If the size of the bullet increases it is like being at close range with a real firearm. It is hard to miss

```
    public void onFIRE(View view){

    if(btnStart.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){
        startLabel.setText("No Firing Start Game");
        return;
    }

    gunANGLE = ivTRI.getRotation();

    if(gunANGLE == 0.0f){
        ZY -= 200.0;
        ZX += 0;
        pink.setX(pink.getX()+ZX);
        pink.setY(pink.getY()+ZY);
        //System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$ Y "+pink.getY());
        //System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$ X "+pink.getX());

        hitCHECK();

        ZX = 0;
        ZY = 0;
        if( pink.getY() < 40){
            HITorMISS();
            pink.setX(ivTRI.getX()+30);
            pink.setY(ivTRI.getY()+60);
            // rotate gun bring bullet back to breach
            HITorMISS();
            // loose point for missing
        }
    }
```

that is the process of firing here is the collision detection

```
    public void hitCHECK(){

    Rect pinkRect = new Rect();
    pink.getHitRect(pinkRect);

    Rect iv1Rect = new Rect();
    iv1.getHitRect(iv1Rect);
    Rect iv2Rect = new Rect();
    iv2.getHitRect(iv2Rect);
    Rect iv3Rect = new Rect();
    iv3.getHitRect(iv3Rect);
    Rect iv4Rect = new Rect();
    iv4.getHitRect(iv4Rect);
    Rect iv5Rect = new Rect();
    iv5.getHitRect(iv5Rect);
    Rect iv6Rect = new Rect();
    iv6.getHitRect(iv6Rect);

    Rect earthRect = new Rect();
    earth.getHitRect(earthRect);

    Rect asteroidRect = new Rect();
    asteroid.getHitRect(asteroidRect);

    Rect arrowLeftRect = new Rect();
    arrowLeft.getHitRect(arrowLeftRect);
    Rect arrowRightRect = new Rect();
    arrowRight.getHitRect(arrowRightRect);

    if (Rect.intersects(pinkRect, arrowLeftRect)) {
        arrowLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        arrowLeft.setX(-100);
        arrowLeft.setY(-100);
        arrowLeft.setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (Rect.intersects(pinkRect, arrowRightRect)) {
        arrowRight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        arrowRight.setX(-100);
        arrowRight.setY(-100);
    }
    if (Rect.intersects(pinkRect, iv1Rect)) {
        iv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv1.setX(-100);
        iv1.setY(-100);
    }
    if (Rect.intersects(pinkRect, iv2Rect)) {
        iv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv2.setX(-100);
        iv2.setY(-100);
    }
    if (Rect.intersects(pinkRect, iv3Rect)) {
        iv3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv3.setX(-100);
        iv3.setY(-100);
    }
    if (Rect.intersects(pinkRect, iv4Rect)) {
        iv4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv4.setX(-100);
        iv4.setY(-100);
    }
    if (Rect.intersects(pinkRect, iv5Rect)) {
        iv5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv5.setX(-100);
        iv5.setY(-100);
    }
    if (Rect.intersects(pinkRect, iv6Rect)) {
        iv6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv6.setX(-100);
        iv6.setY(-100);
    }

    if (Rect.intersects(pinkRect, asteroidRect)) {

        count = count + 1;
        if (count > 5) {
            asteroid.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            asteroid.setX(-90);
            asteroid.setY(-180);
            timerA.cancel();
            timerA.purge();

        } else {
            asteroid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            asteroid.setX(-90);
            asteroid.setY(-180);
            asteroid.setRotation(asteroidANGLE = -0.0f);
            // These settings make the asteroid follow a new
            // path it continues to come back and attack the earth
        }
    }

    if (Rect.intersects(pinkRect, earthRect)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), you_hit_earth.class);
        intent.putExtra("MSG", 1);
        startActivity(intent);
        stopGAME(null);
    }
    if (Rect.intersects(asteroidRect, earthRect)) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), you_hit_earth.class);
        intent.putExtra("MSG", 2);
        startActivity(intent);
        stopGAME(null);
    }

    if(iv1.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE && iv2.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE&&
            iv3.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE&&iv4.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE&&
            iv5.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE&&iv6.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE&&
            arrowLeft.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE&&arrowRight.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE){

        Long spentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - startTime;
        score = spentTime;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), result.class);
        intent.putExtra("SCORE", score);
        startActivity(intent);

        stopGAME(null);
    }
}
```

this game has four threads running one for asteroids one for arrowLeft and arrowRing asteroids one for a earth Image view and an asteroid that chases the earth that has to be hit more than 5 times to make it disapear

Comment: this is a lot of help,but do you think I should go and move to libgdx? will the app function the same? I'm worried it will be more efficient and functional if I move to libgdx

Comment: @francisEscolar LIBgdx will not solve your problem but feel free to try it The process in my eyes just adds another layer of learning Develop your Android Java skills then move on to new process for coding If the answer was helpful consider a up vote if not that is good

Comment: @francisEscolar All learning takes time Rather than rewrite your app write a test app to see what we are talking about James_Duh offered some good advice Any way try this link http://codingwithsara.com/category/blog/youtube/android/ and look at the tutorial Catch the Ball with the Bonus offered you can download the code